# In Dart language... How i can know if getter called method or no?

Tags: flutter, dart, getter-setter, getter

For example I have this getter

```dart
class MyClass<T>{
  MyClass(this._value);
  T _value;
  T get value{
    print("Getter called");
    return _value
  }
}
            
MyClass myClass = MyClass([]);
// How I can check if getter called like this:
myclass.v;
// or like this (call method from it)
myClass.v.add();
```

I hope understand me (my english is not good)

Comment: The getter returns an object to the caller.  The getter has no control over what the caller does with that object afterward.

Comment: OK Thank you, i will search in another imlemenatation